# Heroku and Mod_security: How to disable it

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku, matomo, mod-security

I'm trying to install Piwik on Heroku to keep all my company's applications on the same host. I got some other errors suppressed, but this one has stumped me:

`GET request to piwik.php failed. Try whitelisting this URL from HTTP Authentication and disable mod_security (you may have to ask your webhost).
After making this change, restart your web server.`

Heroku doesn't have any guide on disabling mod_security and I've tried disabling it through my `.htaccess` file with no luck.

What is the whitelisting the url from http auth mean? Is that easier to configure than hacking the stack to disable mod_security?

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Comment: Just pushed the application to heroku. Once it was on the app I had to tweak a couple settings for php settings. I also tried using Piwik's pro service and it still isn't recieving data. 

I'm installing the tracking code manually into my application view. It's making the request to piwik.php with all the parameters.

Comment: FYI I recommend not using Heroku, I have had many reports of Piwik being a nightmare to run on this for various reasons (unfortunately). Try a more "classic" VPS maybe?